# How to preprocess a large pandas dataframe in Python for k-means

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, k-means

I want to find the value of 'k' in k-means algorithm using the elbow method. I am using python and pandas. My .csv file is about 500MB(containing almost 1M rows). The problem is that because of `MinMaxScaler` everything is converted to `float64` and thus I get a `MemoryError` (tried to read a few rows and it worked).

So far I tried to run it localy(MacBook Pro - 16GB DDR4) and on EC2 instance (free Tier) both as a python and pyspark file (in all cases I got a `MemoryError`). As concerning the pyspark (since I am not an expert) I created a `SparkSession` and created a `main` and a `if __name__==__main__`.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_csv('prosepexergasia.csv',low_memory = False)

categorical_features = ['vendor_name', 'ship_from', 'market', 
'category_cl' ]
continuous_features = ['price']

for col in categorical_features:
    dummies = pd.get_dummies(data[col], prefix=col)
    data = pd.concat([data, dummies], axis=1)
    data.drop(col, axis=1, inplace=True)

mms = MinMaxScaler()
mms.fit(data)
data_transformed = mms.transform(data)

Sum_of_squared_distances = []
K = range(1,15)
for k in K:
    km = KMeans(n_clusters=k)
    km = km.fit(data_transformed)
    Sum_of_squared_distances.append(km.inertia_)
```

My question is how can I resolve this issue? Should I just launch a "larger" EC2 instance (with more memory) and run it as pandas dataframe? Can I distribute the job in python? Should I focus on pySpark? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please include all necessary imports. At what point do you get a `MemoryError`?

Comment: @TammoHeeren Update: I am getting the error in `dummies = pd.get_dummies(data[col], prefix=col)` (EC2).